# Simplify and smooth path in Paper.js

Tags: javascript, coffeescript, paperjs

I would like to make a very simple and intuitive drawing tool with paperjs. The user would be able to draw a path, and manipulate it afterward, simply by dragging, adding and deleting key points (no complicated handles).

For now, once the user has drawn its path, it is simplified. Then anytime the user makes a change, the path is smoothed.

This is an very nice and simple way to draw and modify things, since the user does not have to worry about complex handles.

The problem is that the smoothed path is not equal to the simplified path. So I am wondering if it could be possible to implement another simplify() function which would returned a simplified, accurate and smoothed version of the path (the resulting path would not be modified by a call to smooth() ).

[Here](https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio/workspace/drawings/DrawPath.html) is an example of what I have done, you can see that the curve changes as soon as one selects any key point.
You can find the sources [here](https://c9.io/arthursw/oiio), under drawings > DrawPath.coffee ( use 'coffee --watch --compile drawings/drawPath.coffee' in the terminal to compile on the fly )

I now that it is a complex problem, and I will also let the user manipulate handles if he wants to, but I think this simplified version of the curve tool can be really handy.

Comment: Are you also simplifying the path every time someone is moving a point? Maybe it would be enough to just do it after the first draw is done. There is also [work being done](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/issues/338) on another smooth function that is less obtrusive.

Comment: I simplify the path only once, but then I smooth it every time it changes. Thanks for the link about smoothing functions.

Comment: Maybe try to use the new code from [the mentioned branch](https://github.com/paperjs/paper.js/tree/new-smooth). I think the result of the new smooth function is a bit more consistent and should not change the curve on points that were not moved. But keep in mind that the rest of the code in this branch is a bit behind.